# como puedo acceder a una propiedad dentro de un array de objetos con reduce()?

Tags: javascript, array, reduce

Necesitaría ayuda con este código, espero se entienda bien.

El problema me pide que: *"Dentro de un objeto(1) cree una función que retorne la suma total de bicis vendidas, utilizando el método reduce()"*

El tema está en que no se si estoy accediendo bien a esa propiedad.
"**bicicletas**" es un array de objetos con distintas propiedades,también está dentro del objeto(1), era un archivo JSON y lo pase a array de objetos para luego traerlo como módulo propio.

Cuando ejecuto el codigo me tira `NaN`.

```js
let dhBici = {
  totalDeVentas: function() {
    let sumaTotal;
    let bicisVendidas = this.bicicletas.filter(function(estadoActual) {
      return estadoActual.vendida == "Si"
    })
    sumaTotal = bicisVendidas.reduce(function(total, precio) {
      precio = bicisVendidas.precio
      return total + precio;
    }, 0)
    return sumaTotal;
  },
  bicicletas: [{
    "id": 1,
    "Marca": "Fierce",
    "Modelo": "FM18F29AM210",
    "Rodado": 16,
    "año": "2022",
    "Color": "Negro",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 17,
    "Tipo": "Paseo",
    "Precio": 37000,
    "vendida": "Si"

  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "Marca": "Olmo",
    "Modelo": "Regal",
    "Rodado": 28,
    "año": "2020",
    "Color": "Celeste",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 15,
    "Tipo": "Retro",
    "Precio": 24000,
    "vendida": "No"

  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "Marca": "Halley",
    "Modelo": "Sunshine",
    "Rodado": 29,
    "año": "2021",
    "Color": "Rojo",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 16,
    "Tipo": "Triatlon",
    "Precio": 29000,
    "vendida": "No"

  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "Marca": "SLP",
    "Modelo": "Techno",
    "Rodado": 16,
    "año": "2019",
    "Color": "Gris",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 15,
    "Tipo": "Paseo",
    "Precio": 19000,
    "vendida": "No"

  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "Marca": "SLP",
    "Modelo": "Sunshine",
    "Rodado": 16,
    "año": "2021",
    "Color": "Gris",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 15,
    "Tipo": "Paseo",
    "Precio": 28000,
    "vendida": "Si"

  }]
}
console.log(dhBici.totalDeVentas());
```

Primera vez que hago una pregunta por aca, si hay algo mal me avisan

Comment: Tu código está incompleto. Si tú dices que arroja `NaN`, al presionar "Ejecutar" debería ver ese NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes 2 errores:

- El método [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) como segundo parámetro de la función a ejecutar pasa el valor del arreglo en la posición 0 en la primera llamada; así sucesivamente hasta recorrerlo completamente. En este caso sería el objeto con toda la info de la **"bici"**.
- La propiedad con el precio de la "**bici**" es "Precio" (*primer letra en mayúscula*)

#### Solución:

Realizando estas correciones, tu código podrías quedar así:

```javascript
//                                                 ˅  cambia nombre de parámetro
sumaTotal = bicisVendidas.reduce(function(total, bici) {
  //              ˅ Uso de parámetro y propiedad correcta
  return total + bici.Precio;
}, 0);
```

Código completo:

```js
let dhBici = {
  totalDeVentas: function() {
    let sumaTotal;
    let bicisVendidas = this.bicicletas.filter(function(estadoActual) {
      return estadoActual.vendida == "Si"
    });
    sumaTotal = bicisVendidas.reduce(function(total, bici) {
      return total + bici.Precio;
    }, 0)
    return sumaTotal;
  },
  bicicletas: [{
    "id": 1,
    "Marca": "Fierce",
    "Modelo": "FM18F29AM210",
    "Rodado": 16,
    "año": "2022",
    "Color": "Negro",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 17,
    "Tipo": "Paseo",
    "Precio": 37000,
    "vendida": "Si"

  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "Marca": "Olmo",
    "Modelo": "Regal",
    "Rodado": 28,
    "año": "2020",
    "Color": "Celeste",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 15,
    "Tipo": "Retro",
    "Precio": 24000,
    "vendida": "No"

  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "Marca": "Halley",
    "Modelo": "Sunshine",
    "Rodado": 29,
    "año": "2021",
    "Color": "Rojo",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 16,
    "Tipo": "Triatlon",
    "Precio": 29000,
    "vendida": "No"

  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "Marca": "SLP",
    "Modelo": "Techno",
    "Rodado": 16,
    "año": "2019",
    "Color": "Gris",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 15,
    "Tipo": "Paseo",
    "Precio": 19000,
    "vendida": "No"

  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "Marca": "SLP",
    "Modelo": "Sunshine",
    "Rodado": 16,
    "año": "2021",
    "Color": "Gris",
    "PesoEnKilogramos": 15,
    "Tipo": "Paseo",
    "Precio": 28000,
    "vendida": "Si"

  }]
}
console.log(dhBici.totalDeVentas());
```